# ErrorBuilder not available for Image.network() in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

To handles errors in image flutter suggests errorBuilder in Image.network(). But the same is not working for me. PFB the Error in image.

[image]

**pubscpec.yaml:**

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.13.3
  infinite_scroll_pagination: ^3.0.1+1



  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Comment: its true: `Container` does not have `errorBuilder` named parameter

Comment: put "error..." into Image.network

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, It worked when i moved error builder inside the image.network section.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: FutureBuilder<TvShowDetail>(
          future: _callTvShowService(widget.movieId!),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return Stack(children: <Widget>[
              ShaderMask(
                shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) {
                  return RadialGradient(
                    center: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    radius: 1.8,
                    colors: <Color>[
                      Colors.black,
                      Colors.black,
                      Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                      Colors.white
                    ],
                    tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
                  ).createShader(bounds);
                },
                child: Container(
                  child: Image.network(
                      'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${snapshot.data!.posterPath != null ? snapshot.data!.posterPath : "test"}',
                      errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
                    print(error);
                    return Text("text");
                  }),
                ),
              ),
            ]);
          }),
    );
```